# Goalseek in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have series of iteration which need to perform goalseek value to "0".
But after series of iteration, goalseek doesn't seems to perform its task correctly.

I've attached resulted goalseek value which is non zero.

[image: Error value description is attached here]

```
Sub BP_design()
i = 1
Sheets("Reactions").Activate
With Sheets("Reactions")
    Do While .Cells(i + 1, 3) <> ""

        ND = .Cells(i + 1, 11)
        LC = .Cells(i + 1, 12)
        FX = Abs(.Cells(i + 1, 13))
        Fy = .Cells(i + 1, 14)
        FZ = Abs(.Cells(i + 1, 15))
        Mx = Abs(.Cells(i + 1, 16))
        My = Abs(.Cells(i + 1, 17))
        Mz = Abs(.Cells(i + 1, 18))
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(62, 2) = ND
        Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(59, 8) = LC
        Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(62, 5) = FX
        Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(62, 8) = Fy
        Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(62, 11) = FZ
        Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(62, 14) = Mx
        Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(62, 17) = My
        Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(62, 20) = Mz
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        .Cells(i + 1, 20) = Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(95, 25) 'F
        .Cells(i + 1, 21) = Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(96, 25) 'e
        .Cells(i + 1, 22) = Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(97, 25) 'K1
        .Cells(i + 1, 23) = Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(98, 25) 'K2
        .Cells(i + 1, 24) = Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(99, 25) 'K3
        
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        
        Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(104, 23).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(105, 5)

        .Cells(i + 1, 26) = Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(105, 5)
        .Cells(i + 1, 25) = Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(104, 23) '0
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        .Cells(i + 1, 27) = Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(111, 23)
        .Cells(i + 1, 28) = Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(114, 23)
        .Cells(i + 1, 30) = Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(116, 23)
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        .Cells(i + 1, 32) = Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(118, 23)
        .Cells(i + 1, 33) = Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(120, 23)
        .Cells(i + 1, 34) = Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(123, 23)
        .Cells(i + 1, 35) = Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(130, 15)
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
              
        i = i + 1


 Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The accuracy of goal seek depends on how many calculations are performed to get there. Try upping the maximum in Options > Formulas

e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/688691/why-is-that-sometimes-the-excel-goal-seek-doesnt-stop-exactly-at-zero

or in VBA use the `Application.MaxIterations` property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.maxiterations

Comment: Thanks fo the response .I'm new to coding, can you help in more detail on how to modify my code.

Comment: Get comfortable with using the site in the 2nd link there (learn.microsoft.com) and you can code anything. Every page has examples for you. In this case its just one line of code which is given in the example on that page. Start with 1000 iterations and increase the value as you need. More iterations = slower but more accurate.

Comment: ,Thanks a lot for the guidance .I couldn't able to solve the macro . I'hv modified the macro to With Application
    .MaxIterations = 10000
    .MaxChange = 0.0001
End With
Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(104, 23).Goalseek _
Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(105, 5)

Comment: With Application
    .MaxIterations = 10000
    .MaxChange = 0.0001
End With
Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(104, 23).Goalseek _
Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Sheets("Base_Plate").Cells(105, 5)

Comment: I've changed piece of code in goal seek as above , but still couldn't get the desired values .Can you plz help on this .

Comment: At work at the moment and can't access Imgr where your image is hosted but I remember it showed you had resolved to a high number of DP already. `MaxChange` is basically going to control the DP sensitivity, so try a much smaller value like 0.00000001. In any event how close to zero do you need to be? I'm no mathematician but some calcs are going to require a very high resolution to land bang on mod = 0.

Comment: Hi Absinthe , I don't know , i cannot attach snap .Basically I need to solve the 3 degree equation (Y3 + K1 * Y2 + K2 *  Y + K3 = 0 "solve for Y"), for a series of list through looping .I'm ok with getting a possible to zero (+/- 0.01) .But I'm facing issues. Is their any way to slove this issue ? if not from goalseek & solver.

Comment: Maybe a question for https://math.stackexchange.com then, or post a new question with more detail.

Comment: HI absinthe , Thanks a lot for your time and suggestions. I'll try to find the solution in the math.stackexchange.com